# Run an Arduino without a PC

Tags: programming, remote-control

I would like to use an Arduino to make tasks in my life automatic - maybe to rotate every morning a motor, or to open a door.

So, can I run an Arduino as solo with no pc needed? Can i connect it to the Internet and can I setup software like PHP and Apache on it to control it over the internet? Has it any protocols like SSH like a normal server?

As an example: I will send over any protocol a signal to my Arduino with a certification and then the Arduino would run a function...

Is that possible?

thanks ahead

Comment: You can run the Arduino without a PC. `use arduino to make tasks in my life automatic` - what tasks do you have in mind?

Comment: i will send via putty to my arduino a command and the arduino open my garden door with electric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will use arduino to make tasks in my life automatic maybe to let rotate every morning a motor or to open the door.

That's the kind of thing it's designed for.

> So i will ask can i run arduino as solo so no pc needed,

Yes, you only need a PC to program it, once programmed it will run without the PC.

> Can I connect it to the internet

Yes, there are Ethernet and WiFi shields available for connecting it to a network.

> and can I setup PHP and Apache on it to control it over it; has it any protocols like SSH like an normal server ?

No.  The Arduino isn't powerful enough to run software like that.  You would normally connect it via the network / internet to a server to process data.  It would just receive simple instructions or send data to the server for processing.

> as example: I will send over any protocol a signal to my Arduino with a certification and then the Arduino is running a function...

I assume by "a certification" you want to run SSL on the Arduino. That's not going to happen since it's way too underpowered for that.  As I mentioned earlier, the Arduino would connect to a server on the internet to receive its instructions, or you could interface to it directly within your local network (say from a smart phone) through a simple web server interface (very simplistic due to lack of memory - a few buttons and text, that sort of thing).

Comment: It is debatable if the Intel Edison can be called "Arduino", but it has an expansion board which allows to interfacing with Arduino shields and it can  run Apache/PHP/you-name-it.

Comment: I don't count the Edison as an Arduino. It's an embedded computer with an Arduino strapped on the side.  Personally I'd rather go for a Raspberry Pi 2 with a chipKIT Pi on top of it.

Comment: From that perspective, Edison is less of a cheat than Yun and Tre.
While both Yun and Tre make use of a separate microcontroller, to emulate the Arduino functionality, the Edison has only one Quark core for certain specific functionality. Last time I checked the PI2, it was still depending on a binary blob for booting, so I don't think it's the best choice. If I have to stay in the ARM filed, I think a BBB or an ODroid are much better choices.

Comment: Bbb is better than Pi certainly, but there is no chipKIT daughterboard available yet.